# How do I use Custom Number Formats to find Absolute Value in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, format, absolute-value

I am making a budget sheet, and I am importing expenses which are written as negative numbers. I want to write a custom number format in Google Sheets which will automatically change every negative number to positive, aka which will convert it to its absolute value.

I prefer to do this with a Custom Number Format, instead of creating an additional column with rules such as =PRODUCT(A1, -1). I could do that part no problem, but I'd prefer to have the numbers automatically change to absolute value in the column where I import the values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this custom format

```
0;0;
```

or

```
0;0;0
```

first one is for positive numbers, second one for négative and third for 0

Comment: So that works to make the numbers appear as absolute values, but the rest of the sheet is still treating the negative numbers as negative… Is there a way to multiply the values by -1?

Comment: You can ABS function for other calculations https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093459